# Get string value or first element of array as string

Tags: javascript, typescript

Have the following function:

```
function x(p: string | string[]): string | string[];
```

How do I ensure that the following just outputs a single string value?

```
console.log(x());
```

I.e.:

```
console.log(x("Hello")); // should be "Hello"
console.log(x(["Hello", "World"])); // should be "Hello"
```

Any shortcut in JavaScript?

Comment: That's Typescript, not JavaScript.

Comment: Pointy: (a) how to edit a post, could not find the button to click. Thx for formatting :)
(b) Yes, code is TS but could be JS as well. Doesn't matter.

Comment: You click on the word "Edit" below the blue tag buttons. Anyway you're probably looking for the `Array.isArray()` method.

Comment: Ok, am afraid that it may look clumsy. So you recommend:'
'
```
const v = x(...);
console.log(Array.isArray(v) ? v[0] || "" : v);
```

Comment: Yes, if that's all you need the function to do.

Comment: I guess your declaration should be `function x(p: string | string[]): string` because you want to return a single string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this:

```
function x(p:string|string[]){
 return Array.isArray(p)?p[0]:p
}
```

Comment: Fine, basically just add some measure to check the p[0] is not empty, i.e. you did not provide empty array. But got it.

Answer (score 1):

One liner, We acn use **arrow function** and **.at**

```js
const getValue = a => [].concat(a).at(0);

console.log(getValue("Hello")); // should be "Hello"
console.log(getValue(["Hello", "World"])); // should be "Hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that `concat` promotes scalars to arrays, and leaves arrays as is:

```js
function x(a) {
    return [].concat(a)[0]
}

console.log(x("Hello")); // should be "Hello"
console.log(x(["Hello", "World"])); // should be "Hello"
```

That is, if you're actually looking for a "shortcut", and not a technically correct solution, which would be not having such a function in the first place.